# Finding the minimum euclidian distance from all points of class 0 to all points of class 1

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

**The Problem**

I have a dataset with 4 columns and ~90k rows. Columns 1, 2, 3 are the features and column 4 is the target class (binary classification, either 0 or 1).

I want to add a 5th column to my dataset that will contain the closest Euclidian distance from row[i] to another point of the opposite category and then sort all rows based on that column. The category is not to be taken as a dimension when calculating the distance.

The feature column names are P1, P2, P3 and the target is T1

**My Attempt**

```
df = get_transformed_df()

df_cat0 = df[df["T1"] == 0]
df_cat1 = df[df["T1"] == 1]

df_cat0 = df_cat0.drop(columns=["T1"])
df_cat1 = df_cat1.drop(columns=["T1"])

#add new columns to df_cat0 and df_cat1 filled with zeros

for ix in range(0, df_cat0.shape[0]):
    for iy in range(0, df_cat1.shape[0]):
        dist = np.linalg.norm(df_cat0.iloc[ix] - df_cat1.iloc[iy])
        #closest = min(previous_min, dist)
    #add closest to row[i], new_col
```

**Reasoning**

I have tried to represent the idea with two nested for loops and by splitting the initial dataframe into two based on the target class. However, this is horribly inefficient and slow and I did not bother trying to finish implementing it as it would compute probably for hours.

**Question**

How can I do this efficiently using perhaps broadcasting?

Comment: Why you divide between 0 or 1? when you calculate the euclidian distance is between which features, P1 and P2 or P2 and P3 ....

Comment: I want to find out which is the shortest distance (the vector i.e. direction is not of importance to me) which need to be added to P1, P2, P3 to force category 0 into the same coordinate as a datapoint which is of the category 1.

Basically how much I have to modify my P1,P2,P3 from point of class 0 to arrive at any point which is class 1 (and vice versa)

Comment: I view the entire row as one point point_category0(P1, P2, P3). It is euclidian distance in 3D space

Comment: I understand now, what you want to do is like find the closest point from category 0 to category 1.
The thing is each point needs to be iterated against the whole dataframe in a 3d dimensional space. Am I right?

Comment: Yes you are right it needs to be iterated against the whole dataframe. I need to find the closest point from every category to every other opposite category.

If I take any row from this new dataset it will tell me the closest distance to a point of the opposite category

Comment: Maybe if you plot the points, you can find some kind of idea about the points which are closest to the other category, and from there, see if you can get rid of a bunch of points far from the category 0.

Comment: This is what I wanted to automate, yes. I want to remove a bunch of points of either category 0 or category 1 which are far from each other. I can't plot this and do it manually as it would mean that I'd have 90.000 points plotted in a 3D coordinate space. I could colour code red for 0 blue for 1 or something but it would still be impossible to remove them by hand.

Comment: Mate, share the dataframe to have a look.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance_matrix.html).

Comment: I don't know if I am allowed to share external download links over stack overflow but I uploaded the CSV:
https://file.io/dCfNDSmD4v0Y

Comment: @QuangHoang I didn't know about that function. It seems to do precisely what I described I will look into it and read the documentation. Great comment.

Comment: @QuangHoang This is exactly what I need.. If you write an answer with the content of this comment I will accept it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to **Quang Hoang** from the comments and his reference to the spatial distance matrix from the Scipy module I managed to solve my problem. I decided to post it as the answer to this question in case somebody has a similar problem.

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.spatial import distance_matrix

df = pd.read_csv("dataset.csv")

df_cat0 = df[df["T1"] == 0]
df_cat1 = df[df["T1"] == 1]

C0 = df_cat0.iloc[:,:-1]
C1 = df_cat1.iloc[:,:-1]

dm = distance_matrix(C0, C1)

df_cat0.insert(4, "DIST_MIN", dm.min(axis=1))
df_cat1.insert(4, "DIST_MIN", dm.min(axis=0))

df = pd.concat([df_cat0, df_cat1])
df = df.sort_values(by=["DIST_MIN"])
```

First I split the dataframe into two dataframes based on the categories (category 0 and 1).

Next I keep a reference to these frames but slice them so that I only keep the features (target column is last in my dataset hence :-1)

Then I compute the distance matrix with the **distance_matrix** module from the **scipy.spatial** library which creates a **(C0.size[0] x C1.size[0])** matrix containing all the distance measures from each point to each other point.

Then I use the min aggregation functions to collapse it into two **(C0.size[0] x 1)** and **(C1.size[0] x 1)** vectors and depending on which axis I've collapsed I insert it as a new column to either **df_cat0** or **df_cat1**.

Lastly I use the pandas **concat** function to stich these two frames back together into one and sort it by the new **DIST_MIN** column.